# How to use a Rails form with a CDN?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cdn, cloudflare

We are interested in using a CDN (like Cloudflare) for our Rails 4 site (on Heroku), which has a form. Is it possible for the CDN to cache the form?

Each time a Rails form is rendered, it should have a unique authenticity token. So does that preclude it from being cached by a CDN? Are there any ways to make it work with a CDN?

Comment: Interesting, what's the use case? I mean why would you want a form on a CDN?

Comment: To reduce the load on the servers.

Answer (score 1):

CloudFlare [caches by file extensions](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-Which-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-) by default

If you're trying to cache something like yoursite.com/form, then you probably want to look at using [PageRules](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-) to cache the actual page.

Note: I would recommend using caution if you use something like cache everything. You probably want to avoid having cached content intended for one user displayed to another user.